# Select count from table based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

**I have a audit table like this:**

```
id  doc_id  datetime      user   event
---|------|------------|--------|--------
1  | 10   | 04/03/2018 | john   | sign 
2  | 10   | 05/03/2018 | anna   | sign
3  | 10   | 11/03/2018 | paul   | reject
4  | 10   | 23/03/2018 | marc   | sign
5  | 11   | 23/03/2018 | john   | sign
6  | 11   | 24/03/2018 | luke   | create
7  | 11   | 24/03/2018 | john   | sign
```

I need to get users and the count of documents they have signed. A user can sign a document n times, but when count the user has signed it 1 time. If on one document reject was called, then all the users prior reject are not taken into count for that document. Also the query performance is very important because there are millions of entries.

**Result would be:**

```
user   num_of_signed_docs
-----|-------------------|
john |  1                |  
marc |  1                |
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect because you tagged MySQL and SQL server (MSSQL) or do you need a valid ANSI SQL cross database query?

Comment: I need a query for SQL server mainly, but in MySQL would also be ok

Answer (score 1):

You create for each row a dummy column, named `type` applying the condition you want, 
with a value 0 or 1 and sum over it:

```
select t.username, sum(t.type) num_of_signed_docs from (
select a.username, 
case
  when event = 'reject' then 0
  when exists 
  (select 1 from audit where doc_id = a.doc_id and 
    datetime > a.datetime and event = 'reject')
  then 0
  else 1 end as type
from audit a
) t
group by t.username
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6822708e702439446ddce23a8caad6ec) for SQL Server
and the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dRbx7nzpoN9bugGPjfxo4p/0) for MySQL
**Edit**

```
select a.username, count(distinct a.doc_id) num_of_signed_docs 
from audit a
where
  a.event = 'sign'
  and
  not exists (
    select 1 from audit where 
      doc_id = a.doc_id and datetime > a.datetime and event = 'reject'    
  )
group by a.username
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=445ad83b26016780420ca658eda98d11) for SQL Server
and the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dRbx7nzpoN9bugGPjfxo4p/7) for MySQL

Comment: I have updated my post. Your  answer was close for the initial question.
Could you try to solve it again?

Comment: when a user has signed the same document 3 times, it should count only once

Comment: Your answer seems to cover all cases. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select user, sum(case when event = 'sign' then 1 else 0 end) as num_signs
from audittable
group by user;
```

Comment: This query will give `anna | 1` instead of `anna | 0` .. Paul rejected Anna's sign event for doc_id  = 10.  Atleast this is how i understand his question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if there are typos. I cannot check spelling. But my idea is to get the latest id of record with reject event and do manipulations with the rest of the table. To optimize the query you can store this id in a variable.

```
SELECT user, COUNT(event = 'sign') AS `num_of_signed_docs`
FROM audittable
WHERE `id` > (SELECT `id` FROM audittable 
                WHERE `event` = 'reject' 
                ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY user;
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you can't  calculate all documents with the latest id of record with reject event, because a reject on one document should not effect the count of users on another document.

Comment: @trokiize It does not calculate records with rejected event but after last rejected! See! It takes the number of the last record with reject (select statement in brackets) and then counts records after (`id > (select...)`). All those records will be signed, not rejected

Comment: @trokiize For your sample `(SELECT id ... LIMIT 1)` will return `3`. This number will be used: only records with `id > 3` will be taken into account in the main select statement

Comment: But the returned number is not good for this problem, because your number is based on the last reject, but this table contains n documents, and so every document has it's last reject on an different id. Your method only checks the last reject and all the documents before that reject are ignored, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Table: UPDATED #3 - Does this put it all together?

```
Create Table signed
(
id Int,
doc_id Int,
dt Datetime,
usr VarChar(25),
event VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into signed Values
(1,10,'2018/03/04','john','sign'), 
(2,10,'2018/03/05','anna','sign'),
(3,10,'2018/03/11','paul','reject'),
(4,10,'2018/03/23','marc','sign'),
(5,11,'2018/03/23','john','sign'),
(6,10,'2018/03/24','luke','create'),
(7,11,'2018/03/24','john','sign')
```

TSQL:

```
if Not Exists 
   (Select Top 1 dt From signed Where event = 'reject')

      With cte1 As
        (Select id as rid,doc_id,usr, count(*) As numb From signed 
         Where event = 'sign' 
         Group by id,doc_id,usr
        ), cte2 As
        ( Select distinct usr, doc_id  From cte1 )
         Select usr, Count(doc_id) As num From cte2
         Group By usr
Else
      With cte3 As
         (
          Select id, doc_id, usr, count(*) As numb From signed 
          Where dt > (Select Top 1 dt From signed Where event = 'reject') And event = 'sign'
          Group by id,doc_id,usr
         ), cte4 As
         ( Select distinct usr, doc_id  From cte3 )
         Select usr, Count(doc_id) As num From cte4
         Group By usr
```

Result:

```
usr     numb
john    1
marc    1
```

Comment: when all documents are signed, it returns 0 for all users

Comment: @trokiize I completely overlooked the obvious part of your effort.  Please see my update.  I added the check to see if there are no rejects and to then perform a standard group by statement for that condition.

Comment: I have tested it again, doesn't seem to work in all cases. I have also updated my post, take a look.

Comment: @trokiize I have applied a new revision to account for additional events such as 'create'. I believe I improved the focus with 'distinct'  – level3looper 24 mins ago

Comment: This time, if a user has signed the same document 4 times, the result is 1 (this is good), but if a user has signed 4 different documents the result is again 1 (this is not good).

Comment: Again not covering all cases. Someone already solved it correctly, but anyway thanks for your effort :) .